# Node properties panel missing in compositor

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, properties

In the compositor, there is the properties panel which allows us to change properties of the nodes added.
It is usually retracted and indicated by a small triangle on the top right, as indicated on the image below.  But it seems to be missing in this particular blend file ( I work with many blend files and this is the first case ive encountered)

How do I enable the panel? The blender version I use is 2.9[image]

Comment: Could you share your blend file?

Comment: Press `N` to expand it

Comment: @marcellothearcane  here is the link to the file https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1puMDEjs-w1tqtHC7YWvvJvUYcrupnW79?usp=sharing

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos this dint work.  I selected the node and pressed key 'N', but nothing opened.

Comment: I can see this too. @Duarte, it shows the sidebar as checked here https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnDwL.png and you can't untick it with `N`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Delete the `Compositing` tab up the top:

[image]

Add a new `Compositing` tab:

[image]

Fixed!

[image]

**Bonus**: You can shuffle tabs around with `Reorder to Front` to get them back to where they were:

[image]

Here's your .blend back again:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton! Just curious, how did you share the blend file like that?

Comment: @VjayalakshmiK No problem! You go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and drop it in there :) It's a free thing provided kindly by the community

Comment: This is OT, but I love your vintage Blender theme :). Win98 vibes...

Comment: @JachymMichal It's the `Xsi` one :D Dark themes are sometimes too dark, especially when having to flip back to emails and other primarily-white programs...